# GitHub not showing languages used in repository

Tags: github

I uploaded my android studio project in java on GitHub but it is not showing languages section.
How do I add languages section. And why GitHub failed to detect languages used in repository?

Repository link - https://github.com/QAZIMAAZARSHAD/Bank-Android-App

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C3il.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These files are considered documentation by Linguist because they're in the `app/` folder. You can use the following.

make a file name called `.gitattributes` this file will override that behavior and paste the following in that file.

```
app/* linguist-documentation=false
app/* linguist-vendored
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I had all my JavaScript files inside of the `env` folder then I just renamed it to `src` and then GitHub finally acknowledged the existence of those files.

Comment: For me, `app/*` only worked one level deep. `app/**` worked recursively, based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774719/how-to-ignore-specific-directory-for-language-stats-in-github#comment135350458_76774719).