# Why is languages section not displayed my github repository?

Tags: github, github-linguist

Why is languages section not displayed on my github repository?

My Repository is https://github.com/alumuko/vanilla-datetimerange-picker

I found a question [GitHub not showing languages used in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694267/github-not-showing-languages-used-in-repository)

So I have added ".gitattributes" in my repository like this.

```
dist/* linguist-documentation=false
```

But not displayed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files under `dist/` are considered vendor files by Linguist by default. Vendor files are not counted in language statistics. You can see the list of default vendor files in [`lib/linguist/vendor.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/v7.16.1/lib/linguist/vendor.yml#L19).

To consider files under `dist/` for language statistics, you can add the following to `.gitattributes`:

```
dist/* linguist-vendored=false
```

`linguist-documentation=false` shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need this line in the `.gitattributes`:

```
dist/* linguist-vendored=false
```

I've forked it here, made that change and now the language share is displayed:

https://github.com/Robson/vanilla-datetimerange-picker

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *pchaigno* and *Robson*.

I added

```
dist/* linguist-vendored=false
```

into ".gitattributes",
then the problem has been resolved.