# How to ignore specific directory for language stats in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, gitattributes, github-linguist

This is my repo structure:

[image]

These are the language stats as detected by GitHub, even though this is a full stack app written primarily in Javascript:

[image]

This is because it is reading the `budget` directory for language stats. How can I get it to ignore the `budget` folder?

I have tried creating a `.gitattributes` file in the root folder with the following line: `budget/* linguist-vendored`, but it's been over a week and I haven't seen a change. I have also tried `budget/* linguist-detectable=false`.

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks :)

Comment: Depending on what the directory tree in `budget` looks like, maybe `budget/** linuguist-vendored`?

Comment: Yup this did the trick, thanks! Had a bunch of subfolders under `budget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linguist overrides use [standard git-style path matchers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), so to match on a directory and all subdirectories and files inside it, you need to use `directory/**`.

Attributes `linguist-vendored`, `linguist-detectable`, and `linguist-documentation` would all have the effect you're looking for here (excluding from language statistics).

Comment: In my case, I didnt have a folder to exclude but a folder to specify. My folder was called 'demo' so what worked for me was : `demo/** linguist-vendored=false` and`demo/** linguist-documentation=false`